# Display Custom Dashlet to only specific user on site dashboard

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have created one custom Dashlet, and added it to site dashboard.

But now my requirement is that, I want to display that custom only for site manager and i want to hide it for all other users.

Can anyone help me with this? How can hide custom Dashlet for all consumers and collaborators.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller javascript (aka .get.js file) add an extra remote.call to get the groups of the current user like:

```
var groupResult = remote.call("/api/people/" + stringUtils.urlEncode(user.name) + "?groups=true");
```

Use the result and eval it, then send it to your freemarker dashlet.

--- Update ---
You can also take a look at the default share-header webscript.
Take a look at the file **org\alfresco\share\imports\share-header.lib.js**

The snippet:

```
// Call the repository to see if the user is site manager or not
         var userIsSiteManager = false,
             userIsMember = false;
         json = remote.call("/api/sites/" + page.url.templateArgs.site + "/memberships/" + encodeURIComponent(user.name));
         if (json.status == 200)
         {
            var obj = eval('(' + json + ')');
            if (obj)
            {
               userIsMember = true;
               userIsSiteManager = obj.role == "SiteManager";
            }
         }

         siteData = {};
         siteData.profile = profile;
         siteData.userIsSiteManager = userIsSiteManager;
         siteData.userIsMember = userIsMember;

         // Store this in the model to allow for repeat calls to the function (and therefore
         // prevent multiple REST calls to the Repository)...
         // It also needs to be set in the model as the "userIsSiteManager" is required by the template...
         model.siteData = siteData;
```

so use this in an if statement in freemarker

Comment: Hi Tahir, Can you please give more clarity on your solution. actually i am a bit new in alfresco, so having less understanding on new things like this. Can you please provide some easy and proper steps to do this.  That will be very helpfull for me

Comment: Hi Deeps, I'll post an update. Then again if you're a starter then you need more time, not to do all the work for you ;). So do some research work on little customization until you're familiar and the implement this.